# difference between select * from tablename where id='' and select * from tablename where id is null

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to know what is the meaning or purpose of inserting a value like-

```
insert into table_name (column_name) values('');
```

And what is the difference b/w above statement and not inserting a value for the column(means adding `null`)

Comment: @Andreas That question is about specifying the default value of a column, not comparisons.

Comment: @Barmer Right, its a slightly different question, but IMHO the answers answer all relevant aspects of '' vs. null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selects records where ID is an empty string

```
select * from tablename where id=''
```

Selects records where ID is NULL

```
select * from tablename where id is null
```

A NULL indicates absence of data where as an '' (empty string) is actually a string of length 0.

For you better understanding:

```
SELECT LEN(NULL) AS LEN_NULL, LEN('') AS LEN_EMPTY_STR
```

would give :-

```
LEN_NULL    LEN_EMPTY_STR
NULL    0
```

Answer (score 0):

in case if you set `NOT NULL` as a property of the column - this doesn't give you an error as a result of insert.

Answer (score 0):

"" can be classed as an empty string

null means null, its a non existent value.

Answer (score 0):

Null mean cell is not initialize where '' mean it is initialize by ''